# tensorflow_hub import error (most likely due to a circular import) on Mac M1 and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conda, tensorflow-hub

The environments are Mac M1 and miniforge Conda with python3.8. I have completed the following commands to install tensorflow and tensorflow_hub:

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos
pip install tensorflow-metal

# tried all the conda commands here (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow-hub) and the following
pip install tensorflow_hub
```

When importing tensorflow_hub on Jupyter Notebook, I got the following error:

```
cannot import name 'LinearSDCA' from partially initialized module 
'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.linear' (most likely due to a circular import)
 (/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py)
```

When importing tensorflow_hub using the terminal, the error message was:

```
E tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:77] Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/api/keras/optimizers
...Traceback...
self._metric = self._metric_methods[self._label_length].create(*args)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.
```

Currently, the version of my tensorflow_estimator is 2.6.0, and the one of tensorflow_hub is 0.12.0. I tried changing the version of tensorflow_estimator. However, the only version of tensorflow-macos that I was able to install without an error was 2.6.0, which requires tensorflow_estimator 2.6.0. Appreciate your time and any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

[Is keras 2.7 installed?](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/819#issuecomment-961699724) If so, please downgrade it via `pip install -U keras==2.6.0` since that's not compatible with TF 2.6. [TF 2.6.2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/compare/v2.6.1...v2.6.2) fixed the upper bounds for some dependencies so that version should work for you out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hi WGierke thanks for your reply. I downgraded keras to 2.6.0 but still got the same error on Jupyter Notebook. When importing tensorflow_hub on the terminal, I got the error ```AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'flags'```. Also, there is no matching distribution for tensorflow-macos==2.6.2.

Comment: Could you share your dependency versions by uploading the result of `pip freeze` to e.g. pastebin.com? Do you also have the stack trace of where exactly that error occurred when you tried importing tensorflow_hub etc?